# Is there a way you can inject a class whose constructor has parameters in micronaut?

Tags: java, micronaut

Suppose I have class A.

```
class A {
    private String s;

    public A(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

and I want to inject A into class B.

So far, I have been injecting classes without constructor parameters like

```
class B {

    @Inject
    private A a;
}
```

But I don't know how classes with constructor parameters can be injected.
How can I do this?

Comment: did you mean `class B{
    private A a;
}`, what king of inject you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think in your example `A` would be a prototype bean because it has an argument that you must provide. Because you must provide the argument you can't simply inject the bean like you would a singleton. You can inject the `BeanContext` and call `createBean`. For example: `beanContext.createBean(A.class, "some string value")`. That would require `A` be annotated with `@Prototype` and any constructor parameters that should be provided by the creator with `@Parameter`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this:

```
@Singleton
class B {
    @Inject
    private A a;
}
```

You could have this:

```
@Singleton
class B {

    private A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```